# How to access current/same/self row column value in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Problem: I have companies who submits audit reports. I need to prepare a report column to show what is NextDueDate based on two conditions.

1. if any FormF table has more than one row, then one year from latest form's End date i.e. "ReportingTo"
2. if only one FormF record found then one year from "RegistrationDate"

Code:

```
SELECT
    F.[ID], enty.[Title (Title)],
    format(F.[ReportingFrom], 'MM/dd/yyyy') as 'ReportingFrom',
    format(F.[ReportingTo], 'MM/dd/yyyy') as 'ReportingTo',
    format(enty.[RegistrationDate], 'MM/dd/yyyy') as 'RegistrationDate',
    CASE 
       WHEN ((SELECT COUNT(F.ID) FROM [db_owner].[FormF] F 
              WHERE F.[EntityID] = F.[EntityID]) > 0) 
          THEN format(DATEADD(year, 1, (SELECT TOP 1 F.[ReportingTo] 
                                        FROM [db_owner].[FormF] F 
                                        WHERE F.[EntityID]=F.[EntityID] 
                                        ORDER BY F.ID DESC)) + 1, 'MM/dd/yyyy') 
          ELSE format(DATEADD(year, 1, enty.[RegistrationDate]) + 1, 'MM/dd/yyyy') 
    END as 'AuditDueDate',
    F.[EntityID] 
FROM
    [db_owner].FormF F 
JOIN
    entity enty ON F.[EntityID] = enty.ID 
WHERE 
    F.[EntityID] = F.[EntityID]
```

[image]

Comment: Use different table alias on subqueries, and review your outmost where clause.

Comment: I did change alias but result is same. also I did not understand you comment about "review" outmost where clause.

expected result of query posted "AditDueDate" should display "02/04/2019"

Comment: Your where is  `F.[EntityID] = F.[EntityID]` which would be stating the obvious (in most cases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid doing subqueries inside select column's whenever possible.

```
;WITH EntityCounts AS
(
    SELECT
        EntityID = F.EntityID,
        Amount = COUNT(1),
        LatestEndDate = MAX(F.ReportingTo)
    FROM
        [db_owner].[FormF] AS F
    GROUP BY
        F.EntityID
)
SELECT
    F.ID,
    E.[Title (Title)],
    F.ReportingFrom,
    F.ReportingTo,
    E.RegistrationDate,
    AuditDueDate = CASE
        WHEN C.Amount > 1 THEN DATEADD(YEAR, 1 C.LatestEndDate)
        ELSE DATEADD(YEAR, 1, E.RegistrationDate) END
FROM
    [db_owner].[FormF] AS F
    INNER JOIN EntityCounts AS C ON F.EntityID = C.EntityID
    INNER JOIN entity AS E ON F.EntityID = E.ID
```